# Call to undefined function mysql_connect() Apache + Mysql error

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ubuntu

I have a Ubuntu server which runs the Dokuwiki and projects system for our LAN

When users access the Dokuwiki they get the dreaded

No ACL setup yet! Denying access to everyone.

and on the projects system appears with the login but once logged in this error appears

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /data/projects/common_code_1/class.Database.php on line 78
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

I have restarted Apache and MySQL but still persists, is it a PHP error?

Please help

Comment: WIthout any code all I can tell is that mysql_* functions are deprecated. And btw have you configured db settings in your project?

Comment: What code do you need? This has happened overnight with no changes so I can only assume something has broken

Comment: Maybe you auto-updated PHP to a newer version that stopped to support the deprecated mysql library. Try to update your wiki too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the proper PHP library. Your wiki seems to need "mysql" which is deprecated. Please update your wiki to a newer version that uses mysqli or you will loose support for it soon.

```
sudo apt-get install php-mysql
```

Comment: Does it not seem strange that this has happened overnight with no changes to the system? I will update this now

Comment: As above: Maybe you autp-updated your PHP to a newer version that stopped to support the deprecated mysql library. Try to update your wiki too.PHP

Answer (score 0):

Check for below settings in php.ini

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

Create a php file with below code 
`<?php phpinfo(); exit(); ?>` 
and load it in your browser. Search the page for MySQL. If you don't see it, you need to recompile PHP with MySQL support, or reinstall a PHP package that has it built-in

Comment: You can just install the package on a standard Ubuntu/Debian server. No need to configure anything yourself.

Comment: above are the steps to troubleshoot.

Comment: Created the page cannot find mysql, Which command should I run to recompile my existing php with sql? Could you think why it would of broken?

Comment: extension=php_mysql.dll and extension=php_mysql.dll are both greyed out

Answer (score 0):

Please Restart your Apache and Mysql .Or You can find in 'Apache Error Log'. Or change the display errors 'off' to 'on' in 'php.ini' file.